# .net 6 WebApi Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel is now available in any context?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

In .net 6 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel' is now avalialble in all classes without adding 'using' with namespace in file?

I have my own class LogLevel and I didn't have any problems in .net 5 or after migrated to .net 6. Now I have new app in .net 6 and I have error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS0104  'LogLevel' is an ambiguous reference between
> 'Common.LogLevel' and 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel'

Comment: That's one of the reasons namespaces exist to make classes named equally distinguishable. Use parts of namespace to make them distinguishable or rename the class in the usings with a "using static" and use that name or ... there are many options.

Comment: Looking at it again did you update your project files while updating? Then remove "ImplicitUsings" from them. For new projects that seems to be the default now. https://www.hanselman.com/blog/implicit-usings-in-net-6

Comment: Ok thanks for the info, that's what I wanted to know!